# 3rd time that I use the rasberry pi, 3rd time that I have to create an sd card

Tags: sd-card, software-installation

I'm a very beginner with rasberrypi. This is only the 3rd time I'm using it.

as, as title, 3rd time I use the rasberrypi, 3rd time I have to crate an SD card because of no signal video.

Is it normal? where am I wrong?

## EDIT

I think it is a "no boot at all", because when I plug the montior I see "NO SIGNAL" in the monitor.

It is a sandisk ultra 8gb, should be ok from that list (that I didn't know so, thank you for the list)

Ohu, I have a Raspbeyy PI (C) 2011.. is it the model?

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific. Can you elaborate on what you mean by "no signal video"? Do you mean a kernel panic or that it doesn't boot at all? What's the brand/model of your SD card? Is it on this list? http://elinux.org/RPi_SD_cards What are the exact steps you're taking to format and write the image to the SD card?

Comment: ok sorry see the edit

Comment: What do the indicator lights do when it tries to boot?

Comment: the red one of the power. the green one with OK blibps a bit when I plug the usb for power and then siwtch off. How does is it suppose to be?

Comment: Are you using a HDMI monitor?

Comment: a beamer, a projector..

Comment: What connector are you using to connect to the projector HDMI or the Composite Video RCA (Yellow port next to audio port)? Also, about the version, no, the Raspberry Pi (c) 2011 is the year it was made in (I believe). If your Pi has two USB ports it is a Revision B, if only one, if is a Revision A.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an HDMI monitor you may need to set the

```
hdmi_safe=1
```

value in the [configuration](http://elinux.org/R-Pi_ConfigurationFile) file.

There is a [troubleshooting](http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Display) guide at eLinux which may help you as well.